How to interpret sleep in metaphysical solipsism?
Sleep is a curious necessity for most beings and impacts health when neglected. How does metaphysical solipsism interpret this regular activity?
Motivation
From a solipsistic viewpoint, sleep could be seen as a bridge between the currently experienced world and the fantastical dream worlds. Could sleep be an opportunity for a solipsist to explore and experiment within these unstable worlds, and perhaps even integrate those experiences into the currently dominant world?
Waking up, then, might be an act of reaffirming the primacy of the world solipsist awakens to. The health consequences of sleep deprivation in the dominant world could potentially be a self-preservation mechanism against losing dominance to a world where the solipsist has spent too much time dreaming. In a way, it shows that the element of surprise in sleep is comparable to the "survival of the fittest" principle, which is not surprising in the real world.
This is, of course, just one possible interpretation, and due to the speculative nature of solipsistic philosophy, it is purely conjecture. However, I'm curious to explore alternative viewpoints that may be more meta, nuanced and abstract.

Why would solipsism have a problem with it?

I guess the same as dream: "I dreamt xyz" now becomes "Im feeling refreshed" IOW for a solipsist there is no such thing as sleep (I guess!!) because we only know of sleep as an anticipation or a memory of  a dream or of dreamless refreshment

@DavidGudeman I feel it is odd for a solipsist to perceive the regular need to sleep.

@Rushi Then the question is why is there a strong need of dreaming or having a memory of dream on a regular basis?

I guess I was too terse. This site prefers questions that show a bit of initiative and research. I was suggesting that you improve the question by explaining what the tension is between solipsism and sleep. I agree that there is some sort of tension there, but I don't know that what I'm thinking of is what you are thinking of unless you spell it out. A quick explanation would be more likely to inspire a helpful answer.

The main reason is control, in solipsism because you are the only thing that exists you would want it to seem like you are the only entity with any sense of realness and so if you are real you should be in control of everything including being active (if one was to be active all the time this would properly establish solipsism) , with a proper thought process one can easily disassemble solipsism and it doesn't take a whole lot but a simple understanding of the human condition, memory and logic. I must say solipsism is by far the most absurd and idiotic position anyone with enough intelligence could possibly have.
I would say sleep actually isn't properly handled in solipsism and actually breaks it. Honestly, I don't even think anyone holds a true solipsist view.

A solipsist might argue they are still active while sleeping. In my question I described how it might work if sleep teleports you to another world where you are as active as you were in the world you slept in.

@tejasvi But wouldn't one be aware of this other world, but we usually don't have clear memories of our dreams at least not every time. Then how does one explain that.

It can be explained if teleportation is defined as a loss of memory of the original world. If a dream is vividly remembered with 100% fidelity, perhaps it could be perceived as real, suggesting that the world hasn't truly been left behind. Yet, we often wake up with only a vague memory of our dreams, fully teleported into our present world.

If I may ask the solipsist who or what teleports you to this other world, is it yourself? And if so, why did you make your world as such. Why not make it constantly just one reality?
